# Elasticsearch sort by date work only with asc order

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an elastic search table with a date field formatted in this way: dd/MM/yyyy.

I've mapped the field in this way

```
{ 
"estratto_conto": {
  "properties": {
     "data_conto": {
        "type": "date",    
        "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

When I'm trying to do a search sorted by 'data_conto' field it works with the ascending sort, but if I set "order":"desc" it doesn't work, it returns the default _score sorting.

Anyone can explain me why?

This is the mapping

```
{
   "estratto_conto": {
      "properties": {
         "field1": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "field2": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "field3": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "data_conto": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
         },
         "field5": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "field6": {
            "type": "string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe both don't work?

Comment: The ASC ordering works like a charm!

Comment: apologize my stupid comment. i'll try to help you but my brain is not there.

Comment: Can you post the query you use when you try to sort descending? And the response you get would be handy too. Thanks!

Comment: This is the query: http://pastebin.com/WCNH3VNW
This is the result: http://pastebin.com/rgSK3h4R

Comment: Oddly I have an example that works in reverse only "desc" is working,

You may like to test "asc" may be returning the insert order and not actually a sorted list?